# Uncaught initialization exception created by servlet, when executing a servlet on RAD

Tags: java, debugging, initialization, jax-rs, websphere

I'm trying to create a new servlet on my app. 
I'm developping on RAD on Websphere. 
The class is this one :

```
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import framework.Log;



@Path("/checks")
public class Checks{


    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6790501052160536787L;

    private static final String NCC = Checks.class.getCanonicalName();



    @GET
    @Path("list")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
    public Response doGetListe() {

        Response.ResponseBuilder rb = Response.status(Response.Status.OK);
        rb.entity("[{ 'test' : ' test ' }]");
        return rb.build();


    }

}
```

I don't have much more details, so what i'd like to know is, where does this error come from? Or, how can i debug it? 
If i put breakpoints on my class, they are never triggered. The error must be before the class is executing. As i don't really know how all of this work, i'd like to have some tips to resolve this error.

EDIT :

Here are the logs :

```
[24/02/20 13:29:32:172 CET] 000000c8 PackagesResou I   Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  cnaf.oma.checkenv.rest.checks
[24/02/20 13:29:32:181 CET] 000000c8 ScanningResou I   Root resource classes found:
  class cnaf.oma.checkenv.rest.checks.Checks
[24/02/20 13:29:32:186 CET] 000000c8 ScanningResou I   No provider classes found.
[24/02/20 13:29:32:219 CET] 000000c8 WebApplicatio I   Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.19.3 10/24/2016 03:43 PM'
[24/02/20 13:29:32:539 CET] 000000c8 ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init Uncaught.init.exception.thrown.by.servlet
[24/02/20 13:29:32:542 CET] 000000c8 PackagesResou I   Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  cnaf.oma.checkenv.rest.checks
[24/02/20 13:29:32:549 CET] 000000c8 ScanningResou I   Root resource classes found:
  class cnaf.oma.checkenv.rest.checks.Checks
[24/02/20 13:29:32:550 CET] 000000c8 ScanningResou I   No provider classes found.
[24/02/20 13:29:32:567 CET] 000000c8 WebApplicatio I   Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.19.3 10/24/2016 03:43 PM'
[24/02/20 13:29:32:975 CET] 000000c8 ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init Uncaught.init.exception.thrown.by.servlet
[24/02/20 13:29:32:977 CET] 000000c8 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Erreur de servlet]-[OmegaEnvCheckAPI]: java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY013 violation de contrainte de chargement de classe; classe=com/sun/xml/bind/DatatypeConverterImpl, méthode=parseQName(Ljava/lang/String;Ljavax/xml/namespace/NamespaceContext;)Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;, pc=0
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$3.run(JAXBContextImpl.java:304)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$3.run(JAXBContextImpl.java:303)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:594)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:302)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1170)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:145)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:236)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:186)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:146)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:350)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:446)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:409)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.wadl.WadlApplicationContextImpl.<init>(WadlApplicationContextImpl.java:103)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.wadl.WadlFactory.init(WadlFactory.java:100)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.initWadl(RootResourceUriRules.java:169)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init>(RootResourceUriRules.java:106)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1359)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:180)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:799)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:790)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:509)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:339)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:577)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:161)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:344)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.init(ServletWrapperImpl.java:168)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:636)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:480)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1114)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:940)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:287)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1881)
```

And here is the dependencies, if you need more, tell me :

```
<dependencies>
<!--  jersey rest -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!--  LOG4J -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>cnaf.ddd.omega.ome</groupId>
        <artifactId>ome-service</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: Updating your question with complete error log would help in answering the question

Comment: Are you using parent-last class loading in your app? If so, for what purpose?

Comment: @Jarid I've never heard about this, but to be honest, this is one of the first time i do something on this app, which is a very, very huge app. I don't really know how it works in details, and there's no one who can help me right now. 
What could be the problem using parent-last class loading?

Comment: Parent-last changes the class loader so that it loads classes from that loader first, before delegating to the server loaders. VerifyErrors like this one are usually caused when the class loaders "see" a class twice, once from the application and once from the server. My guess is that your application includes some XML APIs, and it's causing a duplicate visibility between the server and the app.

Comment: Note that if your app does include XML APIs, they're almost certainly unnecessary. WebSphere (and the JDK) has included spec-compatible XML stuff for a very long time, and it's extremely unlikely that your application requires a custom XML parser or JAXB implementation.

Comment: A JAX-RS resource is not a servlet at all. Remove the `extends HttpServlet` and `init()` method and `throws ServletException, IOException` from the class. Then rinse and repeat and fix/update your question to make it better focused.

Comment: @BalusC I removed what you told me to, but the problem is still the same.

Comment: As @Jared says, you are including some JAR files in you WEB-INF/lib that are conflicting with the libraries already on the server. Don't put any xml/jaxb related stuff on WEB-INF/lib

Comment: @Axel: no, it won't fix your problem, it will just make your question better focused, else bounty hunters may post nonsense answers which confuse you yet more. Jarid basically already answered your real problem.

Comment: @BalusC Ok thanks for tips, and to be honest, Jarid's answer doesn't help, not that it is false, i just can't understand what i have to do. I have a lack of knowledge about all of this

Comment: How are dependencies configured? Via pom.xml of Maven, for example? Or by manually dropping the libraries (JAR files) in /WEB-INF/lib folder of the project? In any case, you should list them so that we can point out the conflicting library which you should then remove (because it's already provided by the server, as indicated by the error).

Comment: Via pom.xml i believe. I edited my question so you can see the dependencies, is that enough? @BalusC

Comment: By the way @BalusC, it is maybe a stupid question, but why the error message is "Uncaught initialization exception created by servlet" if this is not a servlet at all?

Comment: @Axel: JAX-RS resources are all initialized its own single servlet, the `com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer`. The JAX-RS resources themselves in turn don't need to be servlets. Just put `@Path` annotation on POJOs.

Comment: check the content of your WEB-INF/lib directory in the deployed WAR

Comment: @areus I don't have this directory. I only have files in WEB-INF directory, not a /lib folder.

Comment: Do you deploy an EAR? Or only a WAR?

Comment: @areus I have no idea, as I said i know nothing about this app and this technology.. and this is my main problem. 
Btw, about the libraries, I have a directory in Java Resources/Libraries where there are a lot of .jar files, maybe that could help?

Comment: Ok. You posted a snippet of your pom.xml file of the module. It's the only module you have, or you have a parent directory, with also a pom.xml file, and other siblings directories with pom.xml files?

Comment: It is the only module i have, i have only one pom.xml in this project directory. But have few projects in the Entreprise Explorer.

Comment: You say you don't have a WEB-INF/lib, but did you mean in your source? Did you check the .war file on your target/ directory?

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is not a servlet but JAX-RS resource. Second remove jersey dependencies from your pom and use javaee dependency with the scope provided (you may need to adjust version depending on which WAS/Liberty version you are running), as WebSphere provides JAX-RS compatible runtime and you need to include that in your application.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Error you see is related to jersey/xml libraries that you have in your WEB-INF/lib. Remove all libraries form there that are not yours.

Comment: Thanks i will try this. However i don't have anything in WEB-INF/lib, the folder doesn't even exist.

Comment: I did everything you said and i still got the same error.

Comment: @Axel where are you looking for that WEB-INF folder? Did you check your `target` directory and `war` file that is created there? Which version of WebSphere are you using and how are you deploying app there?

Comment: I have a WEB-INF folder, but no lib directory inside of it.

Comment: Ok so @Gas I have a lot of libraries in this folder (maybe 20 or 30). Some are named like "jersey-json" or "jersey-server". So do you think I should remove them? I'm so afraid to do something i'm not supposed to, since i started to work on this project very recently. I don't want to do sh**

Comment: @Axel if you are new to JAX-RS dev, start with tutorial like this - https://openliberty.io/guides/rest-intro.html, which will set you up and provide basics.

Comment: @Axel, it will be worth listing down all WEB-INF libraries